# Efficient data structure for objects in 2D space

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, 2d, complexity-theory, collision-detection

I have a 2D space with objects, each object has coordinate vector and an array of vertexes relative to his coordinate, now I need an efficiency way of storing the objects, this store should be able to add and remove objects, also the most important part is the collision detection:

I want to get a list of objects which have a **chance** to collide (close neighbor etc.), should be fast and simple in about

`O([number of objects with collision chance] * log([number of all objects]))` so that way when there is no close objects it should do it in `O(1)` and not the brute force way of just going over all of the objects in `O(n)`.

Ask if something not clear.

Maybe you know some link on the subject or any good ideas.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Chipmunk Physics](http://code.google.com/p/chipmunk-physics/) and [Box2D](http://www.box2d.org/) both offer efficient 2D collision detection. You could either use one of them, or just inspect their source.

Answer (score 3):

you could use a [quadtree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) for this to check all the nearby objects.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a tree data structure by using binary space partitioning, here is a [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_space_partitioning) about it. This is the most efficient way to my knowledge, of storing information about location of objects in an n-dimensional space.

Here is how it works: Let's say you've got the following field

Let's say you've got a space of 100x100.

You've got 6 objects in there with named A to F the co-ordinates
A(25,25)
B(25,75),
C(25,85),
D(75,75),
E(90,60)

Now, we divide our space into 4 parts, each part will be a childnode of the root node in the tree. The top left corner only contains point A, so that's a chield with one leafnode.
the bottom left corner contains 2 objects, B and C, so they'll be leaf nodes of the second chield.
Now the bottom right corner will have 3 elements in them, which we do not want because of the idea of a binary tree, so we make another subdivision. By doing that recursively, you get a very efficient data structure for finding objects in a 2D space.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a spatial index or a quadtree. A quadtree can be simple a space-filling-curve (sfc) or a hilbert curve. A sfc reduce the 2d complexity to a 1d complexity and is used in many maps applications or heat maps. A sfc can be used to store a zipcode search, too. You want to search for Nick's hilbert curve quadtree spatial index blog.